# Tanstack query loading many many times

Tags: javascript, typescript, trpc

I don't know why, but my trpc `useQuery` functions are loading up every time the user taps on my site or interacts with it.

My code is very simple

```
  const { data: preUploadedImageUrls, isSuccess: fetchedPreUploadedImages } =
    api.trpc.model.getUploadedImages.useQuery(
      {
        modelId: modelId,
      },
      {
        refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
        refetchInterval: false,
        refetchIntervalInBackground: false,
        refetchOnReconnect: false,
        refetchOnMount: false,
      }
    );
```

...yet I see this. How can I even begin to look into fixing this?

[image]

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with the code that you posted. There is no way for us to know how your system works. Perhaps the function where this code is located is called multiple times by some event trigger. My only suggestion is to put a debugger there and see where it comes from and why.

Comment: Since you have those flags set to false, the only reason I can think of, unless the same query hook is called somewhere else, would be is that the modelId is constantly changing thus triggering the refetch.